# Google Classroom API Access requirements

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-classroom, google-admin-settings-api

I'm using this site for testing:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list

I have a project setup with a service account:

- The account was created with read only domain access.
- A project was setup after the fact.
- I then added the account after the fact.
- I then enabled the Classroom API in that project.
- I added the courses scope at the site linked above to domain wide delegation for the service account.

My admin account gets a 200 response with a full list of courses.  My service account gets an empty 200 response.  If I grant the service account domain admin it returns a full list of courses.  I'm happy to provide sanitized screen shots if needed but does anyone know what rights a service account needs short of domain admin to be able to access Google classroom data through the APIs?

Comment: When you say `If I grant the service account domain admin it returns a full list of courses`, you mean the SA is **impersonating** a domain admin? The SA has access to the same courses the impersonated account has access: for example, courses in which the impersonated account is a teacher or a student. If the SA doesn't impersonate anyone, it will only return the courses it has access to (which I think will always be none, since the SA cannot be added to a course, nor it can create one, AFAIK). To retrieve the full list, the SA should impersonate a domain admin.

Comment: Would the above comment answer your question? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer expanding on this explanation.

Comment: That kind of answers it.  Is there any way to get a SA setup without domain admin that can read the whole environment?  Based on what you've said it sounds like it isn't, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Hi! I posted an answer, I hope your question is clarified by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Impersonating an account in the domain:

A service account that has been granted domain-wide authority can access the same data than the account it is impersonating.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832262), **only domain administrators can access all the courses in the domain. The rest of users can only access the courses they are part of** (as teachers, students, etc.).

So **the only way for a service account to retrieve all courses in the domain is to impersonate a domain admin (or have another account added to each course in the domain)**.

#### Service account by itself:

On the other side, a service account that has not been granted domain-wide authority or that is not using this authority to impersonate another account, will only have access to the courses it has been added to.

And since a service account is technically not part of the domain, it cannot be added to a course in the domain (only accounts within the domain [can be added to a course](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users#add_or_remove_teachers) – what sense would it make, anyway, to have a service account as a teacher or a student of a course?).

So, a call to [courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) cannot return any course in the domain: it will return any courses that the service account might have created on its own, which are not part of the domain.

#### Reference:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#:%7E:text=The%20Google%20OAuth%202.0%20system,to%20an%20individual%20end%20user.)