# Getting google calendar, “Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.”

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace

I can create events but when add attendees it returns this error
i followed google guide and every thing is done but i can't figure out what the problem

My code

```
<?php

require_once(APP_LIB.'google-api/vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
//The json file you got after creating the service account
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=checkup-project-298014-b11ac6f73f7b.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setApplicationName("test_calendar");
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'Test Test',
    'location' => 'Test Test',
    'description' => 'Hello world',
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2020-12-18T20:00:00+01:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => '2020-12-18T21:20:00+01:00',
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ),
    'attendees' => array(
        array('email' => 'yasenabdelghany2222@gmail.com'),
    ),
));

$calendarId = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

printf('Event created: %s', $event->htmlLink);

$conference = new Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData();
$conferenceRequest = new Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest();
$conferenceRequest->setRequestId('randomString123');
$conference->setCreateRequest($conferenceRequest);
$event->setConferenceData($conference);

// ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1] is required!
$event = $service->events->patch($calendarId, $event->id, $event, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);

printf('<br>Conference created: %s', $event->hangoutLink);


// printf('Event created: %s\n', $createdEvent->htmlLink);
```

I'm using google-api-php-client

the error:

> Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "calendar", "reason": "forbiddenForServiceAccounts", "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority." } ], "code": 403, "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority." } } in C:\wamp\www\bbb.portal.pfhcheckups.com\app\google-api\src\Http\REST.php on line 128

Comment: So...does your service account have Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority, or not?

Comment: @ADyson yeah it has Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority

Comment: @yasen its not set up properly then or you wouldnt be getting this error message

Comment: i think this is answered[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074200/google-calendar-with-g-suite-account-insert-get-403) in the following question

Comment: @DaImTo i set uped it as google doc described

Comment: @yasen im not seeing setSubject in your code as i mentioned in my answer are you sure you posted the correct code?

Comment: i added it but still the same error

Comment: @yasen _it has Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority_ ...are you sure? Because the API says it doesn't, and I doubt it would be lying, and I doubt it has such an obvious bug.

Comment: @ADyson yes in front of service account the Domain-Wide Delegation is enabled

Comment: Sorry but there must be an issue with that because the API is clearly telling you it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority

Means exactly that.  Only service accounts which have  had domain wide delegation set up on the Gsuite (WorkSpace) domain can invite people to events.

Ask your Gsuite admin to set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#perform-google-workspace-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority) to the service account.  If you dont have a gsuite domain either get one or use Oauth2 to authenticate a user instead of service accounts.

If you have delegated domain-wide access to the service account and you want to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of the user account using the method setSubject:

```
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
```

Comment: it returns that this this user don't have writer access to calndar

Comment: You need to delicate to a user in your domain who has write access to that calendar. the service account is impersonating that user so will be given the access of said user.  Who is the user thats going to be managing this calendar its that user that you should be impersonating.

Comment: did you mean service account for example

Comment: The service account is just a dummy user, which you can grant permissions to (preauthorize).  So that it has access to Pretend that it is someone else.    Lets say you have a marketing manager who wants to be able to invite people to meetings.   You set up the service account so that it can automatically invite people pretending that it is your marketing manager.   The users getting the invites will only see it is the marketing manager.   But the marketing manager needs to have write access to the calendar in order to be able to do this.   So give the user write access and it should work.

Comment: Service accounts used to be able to invite users and then it would apear that the invite came from somenumberofstuff@sericeaccount.com which people didnt like, so now you can set it up so that it will come from marketingmanager@yourdomain.com

Comment: ok very nice it is working now but not sending emails to attendees do you know why

Comment: Did around in the issue forum last i remember that was bugged https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: There is an error service accounts done send emails with invites. Check the issue forum see if its been fixed before you spend to much time digging into it yourself.