# TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect_uris' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-auth-library-nodejs

I want to write an app that can process some of my gmail emails that are labeled a certain way.

The example code [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/gmail/list.js) gave me a starting point for my code (which I've rewritten using promises instead of async await):

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { authenticate } = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');

authenticate({
    keyfilePath: path.join(__dirname, 'key.json'),
    scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    ],
}).then(auth => {
    google.options({ auth })

    gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: "me",
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

- created a google cloud project
- created a service account with the owner role
- downloaded the key file from the service account and copied it to my code directory as `key.json`
- ran the code:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$(pwd)/key.json" node index.js
```

Here's the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'redirect_uris' of undefined
    at authenticate (/home/user/dev/gmail-processor/node_modules/@google-cloud/local-auth/build/src/index.js:46:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/dev/gmail-processor/index.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

It seems like it is expecting oauth credentials with a redirect url. Also, it seems redundant that I am exporting`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` when I include `keyfilePath` when I call `authenticate`. What am I doing wrong, how can I get this code to execute successfully?

Comment: The library you're using is in **beta** mode: [Ref](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-local-auth). Do you want to specifically use `local-auth`? Would the workflow specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60092848/10612011) be an option?

Comment: Did you find a way around this issue? I'm having the same issue with the Youtube Data API.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this problem by using:

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: path.join(__dirname, 'key.json'),
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'],
});
```

instead of:

```
const auth = await authenticate({
  keyfilePath: path.join(__dirname, 'key.json'),
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `key.json` file, you'll have to pass your `redirect_uris`:

```js
{
  ...
  "web": {
   // put your callback here:
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback"]
  }
}
```

After that, it should work. The docs are not clear about that, though. I'm still figuring things out.

**EDIT 1**:

Alright, I got it...

Go to your [credentials section on Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and create your OAuth 2.0 Client IDs if you didn't already and download the JSON file. Use that JSON file as your `keys.json`. It worked for me :)